# What is the correct syntax for a map that contains more than one value and getting converted to array

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it the correct syntax? The map contains more than one value and getting converted to array.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("os", "%"+( ((ArrayList<String>)map.get("os") ).toArray())+"%" ) )
```

is it the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: Aren't you trying to use `IN` SQL operator? Depending on what's `ArrayList.toString()` produces isn't a good idea.

Comment: Correct syntax? Or just correct? Your IDE should tell you in milliseconds whether or not it's correct syntax.

Comment: What does the `map.get("os")` list contain, and what do you want to compare the `os` persistent property with? It's syntactically correct, but I'm 100% sure it won't have the effect you want. What effect do you want?

Comment: @John, its not showing any result.

Comment: Instead of concatenating `%`s, use `org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions.like(String, String, MatchMode)` method with `org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode.ANYWHERE`. But don't `LIKE` with `toString()`ed array

Comment: actually the database 'os' column contains some sentence with words like android, blackberry os etc. And the map contains the os names which comes from the client side like Android OS, Windows 7 OS. And i want to compare and if its finds a match then show that os. Previously i was using SQL IN operator but due to database structure change, it is nt possible to direct a IN search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the entries in map and for each one add a

```
 Restrictions.like("os", "%"+entry+"%" )
```

Join those together with

```
 Restrictions.or(...)
```

Add the complete set to the criteria using

```
 criteria.add
```